# How I call HTML tag function from angular component

Tags: angular

I need to call my HTML tag `drawer.toggle()` function from angular component. as event is coming from some other sibling component.
This is HTML code:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer #drawer>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    </mat-drawer>
    <div class="example-sidenav-content">
      <button type="button" mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        Toggle sidenav
      </button>
    </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

This is my angular component function.
please not here, function is being called by other angular sibling component using `EventEmitter` and I need to toggle this side navigation bar.

```
toggleSideNav($event){
  //need to call that HTML drawer.toggle() from here
}
```

Thanks for help.
Later i will be removing that `button` from HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**If your angular version is > 9**

the `static` is by default `false`;

```js
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('drawer', {static: true}) drawer: MatDrawer;

toggleSideNav($event){
  // need to call that HTML 
  this.drawer.toggle() from here
}
```

**If your angular version is 8**

```js
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('drawer', {static: true}) drawer: MatDrawer;

toggleSideNav($event){
  // need to call that HTML 
  this.drawer.toggle() from here
}
```

**if your angular version is < 8**

```js
@ViewChild('drawer') drawer: MatDrawer;
```

Comment: Why would you make static true? I don't see a good reason for that and this is the deprecated value.

Comment: @IngoBürk in angular 8 static option is required

Comment: you need to make `static: false` when parent elements or the current element have `*ngIf` directive

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan, thanks..`@ViewChild` worked as I am using angular8.

Comment: @mahipalsingh But please have a look at the second answer too, I think in your case it is more convenient to use.

Comment: "static" is required, but the better value is true and it should be set to true when possible. That was my point.

Answer (score 3):

Pass ref (drawer), as parameter to function in typescript and toggle from component function.

**HTML**

```html
<button type="button" mat-button (click)="toggleSideNav(drawer)">
```

**Component**

```js
toggleSideNav(drawer) {
   drawer.toggle()
}
```

here is the stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8n9iqt

Comment: no it did not work.. now code is working using `@ViewChild` as mention by someone as solution.

Comment: Have you tried as i have mentioned, or in method you have used `event`?

Comment: @mahipalsingh Please have a look at the example